# Many to one join help for flat file

Tags: join, one-to-many, flat-file, flat

I’m not sure if this has already been asked – I looked around for quite a bit but couldn’t find anything.

My end result is to get data from several of my SQL database tables into a comma delimited flat file. Normally this would not be a problem but due to their many to one relationship and the format I’m forced to put it in it’s proving to be.

1st I’ve got one table, the Report table which has all basic info for a report. For example

```
CREATE TABLE tblReportExample
(
    ReportID int,
    ReportMonth smalldatetime,
    ReportDetails varchar(500)
)
```

2nd I’ve got another table with cases for each report.

```
CREATE TABLE tblReportCasesExample
(
    ReportID int,
    ReportCase varchar(50)
)
```

3rd I have a flat file definition with the following:

ReportID,
ReportMonth,
ReportDetails,
ReportCase1,
ReportCase2,
ReportCase3

What I need to do is add take the top three cases from the tblReportCasesExample for a report, join it somehow with the data in tblReportExample and add it to the flat file as ReportCase1, 2 and 3.

I’ve been looking at this thing all day and just can’t figure it out.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "top 3" cases, how is the top 3 determined? By Date, or something else?

Comment: "Top 3" is any three cases for that report (ReportID.) There's no method to the madness. It's just on my side I can have unlimited cases for a report and they only have room in their flat file for 3.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested update to your question:  Not just "flat file", but "CSV file".  Presumably, the CSV file is an export to another system, or just to somebody who likes to view things in Excel  :-)

Another comment from an old timer (meaning, sombody who has done MUCH file transfer system integration work):  Not all the world is an SQL database.  Especially if you don't need "ACID" for a task (other than a transaction around the initial extract(s)).

Dump (the relevant portions of) the two tables into a pair of CSV files.  Then assemble the final CSV file "procedurally".  The Practical Extraction and Reporting Language (aka "perl") is a good tool for this sort of thing, but there are others.

Read the "tblReportCasesExample" data into an indexed data structure of some kind.

Iterate through the "tblReportExample" data:

- select your "favorite" tblReportCasesExample entries
- dump the tblReportExample fields, followed by the select (key) values from the relevant tblReportCasesExample rows / lines.

Find a CSV handling library if you have any special chars in the data.  Otherwise, just use "split" (perl and java both have something like this, I suspect the .NET library does as well).

Need more details / care at all?

Comment: This is a good idea, I'll have to up it when I get enough rep points to do so. This is the SQL that gets ran by a windows service I've created. I suppose I could pull my data into the service code and rearrange it then bring it back into SQL. I just might do that in the interim to get this thing up and running. However I’d like to keep the thread opened – I’m really fixated on what I’m missing in my SQL code. Thanks for pulling me outside of the box Roboprog

Comment: Alternately, dump the controlling table into a temp table (within SQL) and do the procedural logic in a stored procedure.  Iterate through the temp table and add the "1, 2, 3" entries using straight forward, albeit slow, conditional logic within a loop.  Then, just "select * from #my_temp" at the end of the proc.

Comment: Yeah, that's something I can visualize conceptually ... let me try it with a sproc and see how far I can get. Thanks Roboprog

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you're using the correct ids here. I'm confused with what you're after.

As I could understand your problem is either one of these two:

1.
single report points to multiple cases
cases can be assigned to multiple reports

that'd require a many-to-many connection.

2.
single report points to multiple cases
single case can ba assigned to a single report

that's one-to-many

In the 2nd point, I can't see what causes you the trouble, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

The ReportID in the case table is the same ReportID in the reports table. Scenario 2 is my problem. I can get one case with a left outter join but can't find a creative way to get to the other two:

```
SELECT re.ReportID, re.ReportMonth, re.ReportDeails, rce.ReportCase 
FROM tblReportExample re 
LEFT OUTTER JOIN tblReportCasesExample rce 
ON(re.ReportID = rce.ReportID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add more cases to the cases table, and add an id to distinguish them:

```
CREATE TABLE tblReportCasesExample
(
    CaseID int,
    ReportID int,
    ReportCase varchar(50)
)
```

What causes my confusion is why you need the text file?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this on MS SQL Server (which I infer from your use of the `smalldatetime` data type), but I've seen some articles about tricks you can do with `FOR XML PATH`.

```
SELECT r.*,
  (SELECT TOP 3 c.ReportCase + ',' AS [text()]
   FROM tblReportCasesExample c
   WHERE c.ReportId = r.ReportId
   FOR XML PATH('')
  ) AS ReportCaseList
FROM tblReportExample r;
```

The result should have the columns of tblReportExample, plus a comma-separated string of the top three report cases.  Then perhaps in the CSV file, you won't know that some of the commas were part of that string instead of separating columns.  :-)